# longest common subsequence problem of 2 sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is a slight problem in my code, the program never stops, and when turned on debugger i noted that it keeps iterating over and over starting with str1 ( ignoring my while loop somehow )

```
def third_scan(str1, str2, count):
count = max(0, count)
for i,digit1 in enumerate(str1):
    if digit1 in str2:
        for j, digit2 in enumerate(str2):
            if digit1 == digit2:
                count += 1
                if len(str1[i+1:]) != 0 and len(str2[j+1:]) != 0:
                    third_scan(str1[i + 1:], str2[j + 1:], count)
                else:
                    return count

    else:
        return count

def maximum_length(int1, int2):
count_array = []
str1 = str(int1)
index = 0
while index != len(str1):
    str2 = str(int2)
    count = 0
    count_array.append(third_scan(str1[index:], str2, count))
return max(count_array)
```

Answer (score -1):

Использование рекурсии предполагает три составляющих:

1. Параметризация: выделение параметра или параметров, который позволяет описать уровень задачи
2. Выделение базы: при каком значении параметра не требуется рекурсивный вызов
3. Декомпозиция: разбиение задачи на подзадачи

В вашем случае нет пункта 2: не определен случай, когда не производится рекурсивный вызов.

Comment: Я проверяю длину двух строк ведь, что еще должно быть?

Comment: "the program never stops" это означает, что либо условие выхода из рекурсии отсутствует, либо оно неверное, либо оно не достижимо.